# event listeners not removed as Ionic 4 & Angular conflicts with BugSnag addEventListener / removeEventListener

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, bugsnag

Was trying to resolve an issue with non working multiple choice `ion-select` in my Angular / Ionic 4 app.
What I found is that this is combination of BugSnag which I use and `ion-select` implementation:

- `ion-alert` (used to display `ion-select`) `click` handler triggers `HostElement.forceUpdate` and during the update `click` listeners are removed and re-added. `@ionic/angular` click handler removal code fragment:

```
function (elm, eventName, cb, opts) {
  elm.removeEventListener(eventName, cb, opts);
}
```

- Bugsnag intercepts `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` methods and for some reason `removeEventListener` calls (at least for `click` handlers) has no effect. Bugsnag beginning of eventListener handling interception code (just for reference, I believe the conflict is in other place and the method is long):

```
   function __traceOriginalScript(fn, callbackAccessor) {
      return function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        var cba = callbackAccessor(args);
        var cb = cba.get();
        if (typeof cb !== 'function') return fn.apply(this, args);
```

- in consequence after each click there new duplicated `click` handler are added to each button and checkbox click handles are not working correctly (i.e. it is not possible to do more than one change)

I believe there is some conflict in the handlers registering/deregistering code yet not sure how to proceed - possibly some fix is required in either Ionic or Bugsnag.

Comment: I've submmited same issue on ionic github: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19948

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that updating `@bugsnag/js` to version `6.4.3` solved the issue.